# Data validation based on the selection of another column

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I am trying to put data validation on column D based on the selection from the drop-down of column B. Within the drop-down of column B, I have 4 choices, 3 of the 4 choices start with "Lost - " and the 4th starts with "Damage - ".

In column D I want the validation to only allow text length less than 400 if "Lost -" (Lost -*) is selected and less than 550 if "Damage -" is selected.

Obviously I know that my formula is wrong, or I wouldn't be here. Is there a way to do this in a simple/easy fashion?

This is what I have:

```
=IF(B5="Lost -*",(LEN(D5)<400),(LEN(D5)<550))
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Fixed, now can anyone answer?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
=OR(AND(LEFT(B5,6)="Lost -",(LEN(D5)<400)),AND(LEFT(B5,6)="Damage",LEN(D5)<550))
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JClark Please accept the answer if it has solved the problem